# error while installing soap module using npm

Tags: node.js, npm

Hi i am getting the error below while trying to install soap module using npm.
Below is the error

```
npm WARN node-expat@2.0.0 package.json: bugs['name'] should probably be bugs['url']
```

Any help how to proceed further will be much helpful

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the message from NPM, that's not a error. It's a warning, that tells you the package you're trying to install has wrong data in the `bugs` field, which is only one of the various fields available in the `package.json` file.

An related question: [npm WARN package.json: No repository field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json/16827990#16827990)