# Error "npm WARN package.json: No repository field"

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I installed Express.js with the following command:

```
sudo npm install -g express
```

I get the following warnings:

```
npm WARN package.json range-parser@0.0.4 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json fresh@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No readme data.
npm WARN package.json cookie-signature@1.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json send@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json pause@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json bytes@0.2.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json github-url-from-git@1.1.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json assert-plus@0.1.2 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ctype@0.5.2 No repository field.
```

Why do I have the above warnings? Should I be worried?

Comment: By seeing this question one year later, I realize that I mentally erase all these warnings every time I install npm packages. This is something package developers should maybe be a bit more careful about.

Comment: @nha yeah, I usually see those warnings when doing some npm operation and fix them if it's in the package I'm developing.

Comment: for private repos, just add `"private": true` to package.json

Answer (score 1402, accepted):

It's just a check as of NPM v1.2.20, they report this as a warning.

However, don't worry, there are *sooooooo* many packages which still don't have the `repository` field in their `package.json`.  The field is used for informational purposes.

In the case you're a package author, put the `repository` in your `package.json`, like this:

```json
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "git://github.com/username/repository.git"
}
```

Read more about the [`repository`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#repository) field, and see the [logged bug](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3568) for further details.

---

*Additionally,* [as originally reported by @dan_nl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23355019/2083599), you can set `private` key in your `package.json`.
This will not only stop you from accidentally running `npm publish` in your app, but will also stop NPM from printing warnings regarding `package.json` problems.

```json
{
  "name": "my-super-amazing-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: A few months after my answer and I haven't seem any problems so far :)

Comment: NPM 2.14 now does print an error when `repository` is empty and `private` is set to true.

Comment: @Blaise, I don't get any warnings in NPM 3.3.3 by using `private: true`

Comment: Question, why isnt "private" the default, I mean how many npm projects are created versus how many are actually published, is there really more library code than user code?

Comment: The documentation you linked does not explain why the field is required just that it is useful. Technically, it isn't required (warning vs. error) but I am sure someone is going to wonder why the tool cares at all.

Comment: The answer by wortwart below is more up to date and uses the`"repository"` field instead of the `"url"` shown here

Comment: Hi @user2490003, his answer includes behaviour that is _not_ documented, according to https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json.

Comment: @gustavohenke it is possible to configure it by default, in the global configuration "private": true.

Answer (score 411):

You can also mark the application as `private` if you don’t plan to put it in an actual repository.

```json
{
  "name": "my-application",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 56):

As dan_nl stated, you can add a private fake repository in package.json. You don't even need name and version for it:

```
{
  ...,
  "repository": {
    "private": true
  }
}
```

*Update: This feature is undocumented and might not work. Choose the following option.*

Better still: Set the `private` flag directly. This way npm doesn't ask for a README file either:

```
{
  "name": ...,
  "description": ...,
  "version": ...,
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Got notified about another user about this answer. Looks like `repository.private` is not documented behaviour (or it is no longer accepted), according to https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json.

Comment: @gustavohenke: Thank you, it seems you're right  - `private` as top-level property is the better option anyway. Updated my answer.

Comment: "Set the private flag directly" - this doesn't work for me, I had to specify the private flag inside a "repository" section. Npm version 9.6.7

Comment: Surprising -- the `private` property is the official way also in v9 (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#private) while `repository.private` is undocumented and may or (probably) may not work.

Answer (score 48):

If you are getting this from your own `package.json`, just add the `repository` field to it.  (use the link to your actual repository):

```json
"repository" : { 
  "type" : "git",
  "url" : "https://github.com/npm/npm.git"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying to use the full github project file link (including `http://` or `https://`!

Answer (score 9):

Have you run `npm init`? That command runs you through everything...

Answer (score 8):

**In Simple word-**
package.json of your project has not property of repository 
you must have to add it,

and you have to add repository in your package.json like below

[image]

and Let me explain according to your scenario

you must have to add repository field something like below

```
  "repository" : {     
     "type" : "git",
      "url" : "http://github.com/npm/express.git" 
   }
```

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to specify a repository you can add the following lines to the `package.json` file:

```
"description":"",
"version":"0.0.1",
"private":true,
```

That worked for me.
By adding `private`, you don't need to link to a repo.

Answer (score 7):

**To avoid warnings like:**

```
npm WARN project.com@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

You must define repository in your project package.json.
In the case when you are developing with no publishing to the repository you can set `"private": true` in package.json

**Example:**

```
{
  "name": "test.loc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  ...
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

NPM documentation about this: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Answer (score 4):

this will help all of you to find your own correct details use

```
npm ls dist-tag
```

this will then show the correct info so you don't guess the version file location etc

enjoy :)

Comment: I got a response as '--empty

Answer (score 3):

Yes, probably you can re/create one by including `-f` at the end of your command

Answer (score 0):

Try:
npm install package.json,
npm audit fix --force,
ncu -u

Answer (score -1):

use 
    npm install -g angular-cli
instead of
    npm install -g@nagular/cli
to install Angular