# node module install error (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, npm

[image: terminal output]

I can't install any node.js module without the follwing errors popping up. The error codes refer to the package.json file. Any idea why this would be happening would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Not to worry. These are warnings stating that the package you are trying to install must have `repository` field and not `repositories` in package.json. It is a check introduced recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are not errors, they are just warnings. Everything is as it should be, though the module owners should probably clean up their package.json files.

Answer (score 0):

Those are not errors, are warnings.

As I already stated in the same question right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json/16827990#16827990), this is just a new check added as of NPM 1.2.20.

There are so much packages in NPM that still lack the `repository` field in their `package.json` file.