# NPM Warns "No Repository Field" but I don't have a repository

Tags: json, node.js, npm

I'm using node.js at home without a repository, just mucking around. But when I run **npm install**, I get the **No Repository Field** warning as discussed in this [other question thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json).

npmjs.org describes [this new package.json field](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#repository) with two examples assuming my repository is in either git or svn, but mine is in neither. I'm not using a repository just yet. What values can I use?

I tried empty strings, null values, and even leaving the Repository object empty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I remember, you can specify `"private": true` in your package.json, and some warnings will be turned off. But you can't publish such package to npm registry.

Unfortunately, you can't turn off this warning in npm completely. But you can use [yapm](https://github.com/rlidwka/yapm) instead of npm, since these warnings are removed in that fork (see it's README).

PS: that said, if you're publishing something to npm, it's usually better to keep the code in the publicly accessible version control system

Comment: Just to clarify, `private` does indeed suppress this specific warning.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just ignore the warning and get on with your life.

However, you can also try `npm config set loglevel error`.

You could of course just set it to a bogus value such as:

```
"repository" :
  { "type" : "git"
  , "url" : "http://example.com"
  }
```

Comment: Use `npm config set loglevel error` is the best solution.

Comment: No, `npm config set loglevel error` will hide every WARN output, not just the one concerning the repository field. No warnings for external modules etc. The accepted answer is the correct solution.