# npm WARN package.json Stock@0.0.1 No repository field

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I have a project in a personal private git, I downloaded in another computer and when trying to download the packages in `packages.json` i got this error message:

```
pablo@debian:~/Documents/clients/stock$ npm install
npm WARN package.json Stock@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json Stock@0.0.1 No README data
```

This is the content of the `packages.json`

```
{
  "name": "Stock",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Stock App",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-execute": "^0.2.2",
    "socket.io": "latest",
    "mysql": "latest",
    "express": "latest",
    "path": "latest",
    "express-session": "latest",
    "cookie-parser": "latest",
    "ejs": "latest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "socket.io": "~1.3.7",
    "body-parser": "~1.14.1"
  }
}
```

What can I do, to packages to download, and why in my other computer I don't get this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json-no-repository-field They are warnings, not errors.

Comment: Yes I found that, but I dont get why I need a github repository, I dont have one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm WARN package.json: No repository field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json-no-repository-field)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These warnings are just warnings, and don't indicate anything reason that the dependencies would not have downloaded.

The package.json file shown is working perfectly for me. To debug your issue, try removing the node_modules folder and running `npm install` again. Note that if the packages are already in the node_modules folder, `npm install` won't download them again.

If you want to fix the warnings:

1. Before devDependencies, add a repository option; i.e. something like:

   ```
     "repository": {
       "type": "git",
       "url": "[git-url-of-your-project]"
     },
   ```

   The URL doesn't have to be a github one, just whatever you use to `git 
   clone` the project on another computer.
2. Add a file called README or README.md and write a few words about what the project is in it.

Comment: why I need a repository for my project?

Comment: @Pablo You don't. You can just ignore the warning. But you mention in the question that you have one, so you may as well document it.

Comment: ok, so the problem is other then, since the dependencies are not downloading. There is a way I can check for that?

Comment: Yes, sorry, misunderstood the point of your question. Try removing the node_modules folder if you have one and running npm install again.

Answer (score 8):

**Mark your application as private to suppress all warnings** by adding `"private": true`

```
{
  "name": "Stock",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: "*all*" warnings, or just those about repository and README?

Comment: @Abhishek Goel  it is possible to configure it by default, in the global configuration "private": true

Answer (score 0):

I found removing the node_modules folder and doing 'npm install' from fresh seemed to fix my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just add your `package.json` file from

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
```

to

```
C:\Windows\System32
```

and everything will be fine and working. Hope it helps.