# how to fix “npm WARN clear@1.0.0 No repository field.”

Tags: npm, react-native, npm-install

how can i fix this warn ? thank you so much!

mac cmd run

```
npm i react-native-action-button --save
```

I have the following warning:

```
npm WARN clear@1.0.0 No responsitory field.
```

i try all i can try to do, but still don't fixed it

[image: npm error]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json-no-repository-field

Comment: useless @NicklasWinger

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get this warning is that the npm module you install uses / depends on clear. This project doesn't have a repository field.

You can't do anything about this warning, except finding and emailing the owner of this project to add a repository field.

Comment: i think that's all i can do