# npm install is not working. I am getting npm WARN package.json project name (in my case it is NodejsDemo) @0.0.0 No repository field

Tags: node.js

I have installed node.js along with npm module manager. I have created a package.json file and from the root directory I am trying to execute `npm install` command but I am getting `npm WARN package.json` project name (in my case it is `NodejsDemo`) `@0.0.0 No repository field`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm WARN package.json: No repository field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json-no-repository-field)

Answer (score 1):

From [using a package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json)

> - As a bare minimum, a package.json must have:
>
>   - "name"
>
>     - all lowercase

Try lowercase name like nodejsdemo

and you should add repository like

```
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "git://git_repo_link_here"
}
```

but it's only warning and it doesn't affect on installation.

Comment: Where I have to add repositoary??

Comment: In your project.json. On [using a package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json) you have sample project.json, you can also use command npm init to generate a project.json.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create `package.json` file manually then use

```
`npm init`
```

command to create your `package.json` file

> Do this command in your root folder

It will ask to give some information during creation.

After creating file, you can use it.

and if you want to save your new modules in your package.json

just do like this 
for example install `async module`

> npm install async --save

and async module name with version will appear in your package.json file