# Warning when installing mysql for nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

Can't install mysql with npm.

I run `npm install mysql` and getting this error

```
npm WARN mypage@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

This is package.json file

```
{
  "name": "mypage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "testing something with node and express",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mypage"
  },
  "author": "joe",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.15.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json-no-repository-field#16827990

Comment: Possible duplicate of [npm WARN package.json: No repository field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json-no-repository-field)