# How to add a git repo in package.json file

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, package.json

I have an app where I didn't add its repository in `package.json` while doing `npm init`.

Now I want to add repo in the `package.json` file, but couldn't find helpful solutions for me.

Also, I found repository url's ending like this `.git` but my repo address is simply this https://github.com/sonyzach/usfm-validator

1. How can I add my repo url in my package.json?
2. Which format need to add in package.json?

Comment: **See Also**: [npm WARN package.json: No repository field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16827858/1366033)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can just open the package.json file with any editor and add the following in the main object

```
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/sonyzach/usfm-validator.git"
},
```

also I think you should add the .git version

Answer (score 11):

Just run either below command:

```
npm install --save https://github.com/sonyzach/usfm-validator
```

or:

```
yarn add https://github.com/sonyzach/usfm-validator
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add to **dependencies** block in your **package.json** file like

```
  "dependencies": {
    "usfm-validator": "github.com/sonyzach/usfm-validator"
  }
```

Comment: I'm wondering how does it works with private repository?