react-native fast image error when i use android on without fallback
Seems like I'm getting an error message when I try using react-native-fast-image on android. Anyone having the same problem?
<FastImage
  style={{
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    borderRadius: 15,
    marginRight: 10,
  }}
  source={{
    uri,
    priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
  }}
  resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.contain}
  fallback={true} //<--- this revents error but setting fallback={false} throws error
/>;



This lib no longer maintaince, may be you can try: https://github.com/dream-sports-labs/react-native-fast-image

@meowww wait how r they both react-native-fast-image. If i do npm install react-native-fast-image which one am i using?

if you use  npm install react-native-fast-image, you will install  https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image
Cause name "react-native-fast-image" was registered in NPM by   DylanVann
if you want to try package, which i suggest, try command: yarn add https://github.com/dream-sports-labs/react-native-fast-image
or follow here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780250/how-to-add-a-git-repo-in-package-json-file
