# Azure web app tedious

Tags: node.js, azure, module, tedious

I want to use use tedious in my Azure web app to follow this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-nodejs I get the error "Uncaught Error: Module name "tedious" has not been loaded yet" with require('tedious').Connection. How do I load this module in Azure?

The javascript code:

```
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;



// Create connection to database
var config = {
  userName: '******', // update me
  password: '*****', // update me
  server: '*******', // update me
  options: {
      database: 'signals' //update me
  }
}
var connection = new Connection(config);

// Attempt to connect and execute queries if connection goes through
connection.on('connect', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
    else{
        queryDatabase()
    }
});

function queryDatabase(){
    console.log("test");
    console.log("test");
    console.log('Reading rows from the Table...');

    // Read all rows from table
    request = new Request(
        "SELECT * FROM signals",
        function(err, rowCount, rows) {
            console.log(rowCount + ' row(s) returned');
        }
    );

    request.on('row', function(columns) {
        columns.forEach(function(column) {
            console.log("%s\t%s", column.metadata.colName, column.value);
        });
    });

    connection.execSql(request);
}
```

Comment: *"I get an error..."* - what error? We're not mind readers :p

Comment: Apologies. "Uncaught Error: Module name "tedious" has not been loaded yet."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I load this module in Azure?

In Azure, you can install Node.js module through Kudu Debug Console which could be accessed via `https://<your-web-app-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`

1. cd to `D:\home\site\wwwroot` in the console.
2. run the following command inside the wwwroot directory: `npm install tedious`

[image]

Comment: I get the error: "D:\home\site\wwwroot>npm install tedious
D:\home
`-- tedious@2.0.0 

npm
D:\home\site\wwwroot> WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\home\package.json'
npm WARN home No description
npm WARN home No repository field.
npm WARN home No README data
npm WARN home No license field."

Comment: It seems that there is no `package.json` in your app's root folder. You can run the command `npm init` to create a `package.json` file to it.

Comment: I created the package.json. When I do npm install tedious I get "D:\home\site\wwwroot> WARN wwwroot@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN wwwroot@1.0.0 No repository field."

Comment: Actually, they are the warnings, don't worry about them. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json-no-repository-field). If you can find the `tedious` folder in `node_modules`, it means that you load this module properly.

Comment: Well I still get the "Uncaught Error: Module name "tedious" has not been loaded yet." in the browser console even though I restarted the server.

Comment: Could you edit your question with some code you have written?

Comment: Are you attempting to require tedious module in client-side JavaScript rather than Node.js?

Comment: No I dont want it to load on the client side but on the Azure web app side.

Comment: Is the code you provided above included in HTML file or Node.js route?

Comment: In the html file

Comment: We can't require `tedious` module in browser-side Javascript because this is a Node.js module. You should include the code in server-side instead.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that