# NodeJS Azure Sequelize SQL Server - Error: Please install tedious package manually

Tags: node.js, sql-server, azure, sequelize.js, tedious

So I've been developing a NodeJs app locally on my Windows machine. I opened a simple SQL Server instance in the Azure cloud.

While testing this way (node on localhost, SQL Server in Azure cloud) all works fine - everything works.

Once the nodejs rest api is deployed to Azure (excuse my french) all hell broke loose:

```js
Error: Please install tedious package manually
    at ConnectionManager._loadDialectModule (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:81:15)
    at new ConnectionManager (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:17:21)
    at new MssqlDialect (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\index.js:14:30)
    at new Sequelize (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:324:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\util\database.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js:6:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js:459:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
Application has thrown an uncaught exception and is terminated:
Error: Please install tedious package manually
    at ConnectionManager._loadDialectModule (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:81:15)
    at new ConnectionManager (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\connection-manager.js:17:21)
    at new MssqlDialect (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mssql\index.js:14:30)
    at new Sequelize (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:324:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\util\database.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\home\site\wwwroot\server.js:6:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:849:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Program Files (x86)\iisnode\interceptor.js:459:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:973:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:812:32)
```

here's a snapshot of my package.json file :

```javascript
"devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "azure-storage": "^2.10.3",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "formdata-node": "^2.1.1",
    "into-stream": "^5.1.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mssql": "^6.1.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.4.5",
    "sequelize": "^5.21.7",
    "tedious": "^8.0.1",
    "uuid-token-generator": "^1.0.0"
  }
```

The error being thrown/shown on the error page I get back from Azure:

> HTTP Error 500.1002 - Internal Server Error

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'd love some help.

Comment: You'll need to expand on "deployed to Azure". Deployed to an app service? Is this how you did it? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/javascript/tutorial-vscode-azure-app-service-node-01?tabs=bash

Comment: If possible, it is recommended to remove your code from sensitive information and re-create a simple demo to github, which will help us to assist in troubleshooting and give solutions faster.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? If you have a better solution to this problem, you can also send out your own answers to help more forum users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying web apps, application environment factors are important. Azure as the hosting service of the program, there are definitely some environments that are different from local.

So I suggest to visit the website `https://your-app.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` to enter `kudu` and enter the `site->wwwroot` folder To delete the `node_modules` folder on the server. Compress node_modules in the local project into zip format, and then drag and drop directly into `kudu`. Then proceed to the next test.

[image]

You also can run `npm install tedious` in command line, but I failed and don't know why. But I still think this is a good way to solve it. For more details, you can visit the url.[Azure web app tedious](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44134302/azure-web-app-tedious)

Comment: Hi, sorry - i forgot i posted this.
my problem was Azure related - once we deployed the app to a linux server instead of IIS all works fine.

thanks for the help :)