# npm WARN No repository field

Tags: node.js, git, bash, ember.js

[image]

I'm trying to start work on a project I found: https://github.com/cosmicjs/ember-real-estate-website?files=1. I want to set it up to run locally following the directions in the screenshot, but I don't know much about node/npm. I'm trying to set this up to run emberjs in pycharm 2017 using git-bash as my terminal in win7. I have npm and node installed along with the jetbrains emberjs plugin. When I run :

```
npm i
```

I see:

```
....
-- mime@1.4.1
    +-- serve-static@1.13.1
    +-- setprototypeof@1.1.0
    +-- statuses@1.3.1
    +-- type-is@1.6.15
    | `-- media-typer@0.3.0
    +-- utils-merge@1.0.1
    `-- vary@1.1.2

  npm WARN cosmicrealestate@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

I don't know what to regarding the next line:

```
 COSMIC_BUCKET=your-bucket-slug npm start
```

What does this mean? does it have anything to do with "npm WARN No repository field" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm WARN package.json: No repository field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json-no-repository-field)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `npm WARN No repository field`:

   This is a warning message telling you that the `package.json` file doesn't have a defined `repository`. This really [should be defined](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#repository), but won't adversely affect the run of your program.
2. `COSMIC_BUCKET=your-bucket-slug npm start`
   `COSMIC_BUCKET=your-bucket-slug` sets an environment variable called `COSMIC_BUCKET` equal to the value `your-bucket-slug`.  This is a runtime variable for [CosmicJS](https://cosmicjs.com/).  `npm start` runs a command which starts the web application.

Comment: Thanks for your help!