# npm install doesn't show installed dependencies

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, terminal, npm-install

`npm install` installs the dependencies I have in my `package.json`, but it doesn't list the installed dependencies in `Terminal` as it should. Why is that? Here's what I see:

```
npm install
npm WARN section2.4@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN section2.4@1.0.0 No repository field.

added 4 packages from 5 contributors in 1.507s
```

I'm using `Node.js` version `v9.8.0` and `npm` version `5.8.0`, on a `Mac`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of some npm version (I think it was 5.x), it no longer dumps everything out because it honestly doesn't need to. If you want to see what you have installed in your project just use `npm list` or look at the `package.json`.

Comment: That is correct. I double checked reverting back to npm version 3.10.10 and `npm install` dumps all the dependencies it installs. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
npm list --depth=1
```

to check all the dependencies for the packages in your current project

```
npm list --depth=0
```

will list all the modules installed in your current project
I hope that helps

Comment: This is false, the `-g` flag will list globally installed modules - not the modules in the current project.

Comment: You're right @whitfin you shouldn't use the -g flag just use npm list --depth=1

Answer (score -1):

This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16827990/8767886

It's basically just a warning that some fields are missing in the package setup. You'll likely see it on every package install and typically isn't anything to worry about. The line `added 4 packages from 5 contributors in 1.507s` is verification itself that your dependencies did get added.