# npm WARN No repository field,No licence field

Tags: node.js

I downloaded [teams-for-linux](https://github.com/ivelkov/teams-for-linux)

When I try

```
cd app && npm i
teams-for-linux@0.0.8 /home/milenko/teams-for-linux/app
└── ajv@6.5.2  extraneous

npm WARN teams-for-linux@0.0.8 No repository field.
npm WARN teams-for-linux@0.0.8 No license field.
```

I do not know how should I edit licences in package.json

```
{
  "name": "teams-for-linux",
  "version": "0.0.8",
  "description": "Unofficial client for Microsoft Teams for Linux",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ivelkov/teams-for-linux",
  "keywords": [
    "Teams",
    "Microsoft Teams"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+ssh://github.com/ivelkov/teams-for-linux"
  },
  "author": "Ivelin Velkov <ivelin.velkov@gmail.com>",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE.md",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ./app",
    "start-debug": "WEB_DEBUG=1 electron --disable-http-cache ./app",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^1.8.4",
    "electron-builder": "^20.8.2"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "teams-for-linux",
    "asar": false,
    "linux": {
      "category": "Network;Chat",
      "packageCategory": "net",
      "executableName": "teams",
      "synopsis": "Microsoft Teams for Linux",
      "description": "Unofficial Microsoft Teams client for Linux using Electron. It uses the Web App\n and wraps it as a standalone application using Electron.",
      "desktop": {
        "Name": "Microsoft Teams for Linux",
        "Comment": "Unofficial client for Microsoft Teams for Linux",
        "StartupWMClass": "teams-for-linux"
      },
      "target": [
        "rpm",
        "deb",
        "pacman",
        "tar.gz"
      ]
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

I have read licence in licence.md but I do not have a clue if I shoud put unlicenced or what.
EDIT
I have tried

```
 "license": "UNLICENSED",
```

Got the same warning as I posted before.

My node version is 4.2.6.

Comment: This is just a notice logged as a warning that those 2 fields are not in the module's package.json file. You can ignore it. More info here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json-no-repository-field

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm WARN package.json: No repository field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json-no-repository-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `WARN`, not `ERROR`.

It warn because may be you forgot `license` and `repository`.

You don't need have `license` and `repository`.

Try use this :

```
"repository": {
  "type": "git",
  "url": "https://github.com/ivelkov/teams-for-linux.git"
}
```

And if you don't have, don't need add it, check [SPDX License List](https://spdx.org/licenses/).