# npm install No repository field

Tags: node.js, npm

Ok so when I do my lil "npm install" on Webstorm it says:

```
npm WARN Configuration_de_base@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\fsevents):
```

```
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

and nothing works I am new to this so I dont know what to do or change :(
this message appears on schools computer and on my pc at home

Comment: You are attempting to install packages, but you don't have a `package.json` file letting npm know what you want to install

Comment: Here is more information about `No repository field.` warning. You might want to check it out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json-no-repository-field

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm WARN package.json: No repository field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json-no-repository-field)