# How can I fix npm errors and warnings? Does 'npm audit fix' work?

Tags: npm, npm-install, npm-scripts, npm-start, lite-server

How can I fix npm errors and warnings? It worked before... But now it doesn't work... Also does `npm audit fix` work?

> npm -v
> 6.14.6 node -v v12.18.4
>
> npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit
> this file. npm WARN meeting@1.0.0 No description npm WARN
> meeting@1.0.0 No repository field.
>
> - lite-server@2.5.4 added 217 packages from 213 contributors and audited 217 packages in 8.82s
>
> 4 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
>
> found 1 low severity vulnerability   run `npm audit fix` to fix them,
> or `npm audit` for details

> Users-MacBook-Pro:meeting user$ npm fund
> meeting@1.0.0 ├─┬ https://github.com/sponsors/jonschlinkert │ └──
> picomatch@2.2.2 ├─┬ https://github.com/sponsors/RubenVerborgh │ └──
> follow-redirects@1.13.0 ├─┬ https://github.com/sponsors/sindresorhus │
> └── p-limit@2.3.0 └─┬ https://github.com/chalk/ansi-styles?sponsor=1
> └── ansi-styles@4.2.1

> Users-MacBook-Pro:meeting user$ npm audit fix npm WARN meeting@1.0.0
> No description npm WARN meeting@1.0.0 No repository field.
>
> up to date in 0.69s
>
> 4 packages are looking for funding   run `npm fund` for details
>
> fixed 0 of 1 vulnerability in 217 scanned packages   1 vulnerability
> required manual review and could not be updated
> Users-MacBook-Pro:meeting user$

Comment: It's better to wrap console output in a quote or code block. If you put it in like normal text then it's hard to find your question in it. There's not much to fix. Some npm packages have vulnerabilities found over time. Mostly it goes away when you update your dependencies. As for your package (meeting@1.0.0) WARN. Happens if you initiate your package with default values (`npm init -y`). It doesn't impact how your package works and you don't need to do anything about it if it's local only project. Check [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json) for more info.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm WARN package.json: No repository field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16827858/npm-warn-package-json-no-repository-field)